# Run many simulations simultaneously

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to run many random deposition simulations in order to analyze the statistics.

The individual simulations aren't dependent on each other, but each produces a 1-D numpy array and I want my result as a 2-D array composed of these 1-D arrays.

I know basically nothing about parallel computing so I have only have two ideas how to achieve this:

1. Simple for-loop which will take days to run (I'm not in hurry after all)
2. Run the same file many, each with shorter for-loop, let OS take care of distributing CPU power among the runs and join the files after everything is finished

However, I think that there must be a better way to do this. My current code is following:

```
L = 60
N = 100
T = 100

hrubost_relax = np.zeros((N,T))

for n in range(0,N):
    level = np.zeros((T,L))
    heights = np.zeros(level.shape[1])

    for t in range(1,level.shape[0]):
        pos = np.random.randint(level.shape[1])

        left = heights[pos-1] if pos-1>0 else heights[-1]
        right = heights[pos+1] if pos+1<L else heights[0]

        if left<heights[pos]:
            if right<heights[pos]:
                direction = np.random.randint(2)*2-1
                heights[(pos+direction)%L] += 1
            else:
                heights[pos-1] += 1
        elif right<heights[pos]:
            heights[(pos+1)%L] += 1
        else:
            heights[pos] += 1

        hrubost_relax[n,t] = heights.std()/L
```

I want to parallelize the outer for-loop

**edit to show my solution with multiprocessing.Pool**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

L = 60
N = 1000
T = 100000

hrubost_relax = np.zeros((N,T))

def deposition(n):
    level = np.zeros((T,L))
    heights = np.zeros(level.shape[1])
    w = np.zeros(T)

    for t in range(1,level.shape[0]):
        pos = np.random.randint(level.shape[1])

        left = heights[pos-1] if pos-1>0 else heights[-1]
        right = heights[pos+1] if pos+1<L else heights[0]

        if left<heights[pos]:
            if right<heights[pos]:
                direction = np.random.randint(2)*2-1
                heights[(pos+direction)%L] += 1
            else:
                heights[pos-1] += 1
        elif right<heights[pos]:
            heights[(pos+1)%L] += 1
        else:
            heights[pos] += 1

        w[t] = heights.std()/L

    return w

p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
for i,x in enumerate(p.map(deposition, range(N))):
    hrubost_relax[i] = x
```

Comment: Python can't really parallelize due to the GIL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threading cannot give you any speedup on this problem if you are using the CPython implementation due to its use of a global interpreter lock, which only allows a single thread to be executing at any time (I am assuming the computations are CPU-bound). If you have multiple processors in your computer, however, the [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)
will let you run a number of processes in parallel. There would still be no real value to trying to run more processes than you have processors for, however, so you should consider using [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)